# Converting OCaml to F#: Is there a port of the num module to F#

Tags: f#, ocaml

I am converting several modules based on OCaml to F#. The OCaml code uses the num type from the [num module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Num.html).

> type num =
>   | Int of int
>   | Big_int of Big_int.big_int
>   | Ratio of Ratio.ratio

While I have been lucky enough for this convertion to change the OCaml num variables to just a F# int type, I was wondering if anyone knows of a public port of the num module to F#.

If you are sure the answer is no, that's all I need. I know people frown on short answers, but that is all I need if the answer is no.

Comment: Why not using [rational-number module](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/fsharp.powerpack/Microsoft.FSharp.Math.type_BigNum.html) from [F# Powerpack](https://github.com/fsharp/powerpack/blob/master/src/FSharp.PowerPack/math/q.fs)?

Comment: Didn't know about it. Thanks. I would try it right now but still have several modules to convert and don't want to switch gears in the middle. Did a quick look and didn't see undefined and infinity defined, but I can always send feedback to Tomas.

Comment: If there are no undefined and infinity, you could handle them directly in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [FSharp.Compatibility.OCaml.Num.fs](https://github.com/jack-pappas/FSharp.Compatibility/blob/master/FSharp.Compatibility.OCaml/Num.fs)  by [Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197411/jack-p)